# How access to a variable within inner class Android

Tags: android, loops, variables, event-handling, inner-classes

I've created programmatically 4 radio groups. The problem comes, when i try to use `setOnClickListener` through an inner class, that needs access to the iteration variable (i) of the loop used to declare the radio groups. I tried also to have the iterator variable final, but it didn't work. I need to set all 4 radio groups `clearCheck()`. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    **RadioGroup[] radioGroup;**

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        radioGroup = new RadioGroup[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            radioGroup[i] = new RadioGroup(this);

            finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    **radioGroup[i].clearCheck();**
                }
            });
            linearLayout.addView(radioGroup[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is: `local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final`
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first problem: **`local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final`** (or *how to access to a variable within inner class* in the title), you can clear this problem just by copying value of `i` to another final valiable (ex. `j`). Then use the copied one in the inner class.

```
final int j = i;
finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        radioGroup[j].clearCheck();
    }
});
```

This technique is frequently used.

---

For the next problem: **`clearCheck()` is applied only to the 4th radio group**. This is because you can set a single `OnClickListener` to the `finishButton` at once. That is the last set one for the 4th group was only valid.

So you should set only a single `OnClickListener`, and in the listener you can invoke `clearCheck` for all of RadioGroups. Then below will solve your problem.

```
radioGroup = new RadioGroup[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    radioGroup[i] = new RadioGroup(this);
    linearLayout.addView(radioGroup[i]);
}

finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            radioGroup[i].clearCheck();
        }
    }
});
```

Note that so this solution clears your problem more basically that clears *`local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final`* error, so the first solution which I suggested above will be no more needed. You don't need to *access to a variable within inner class* in the title any more.

Comment: Thanks, i already done this but the `clearCheck()` is applied only to the 4'th radio group. I need to set all 4 radio groups `clearCheck()`, not only one.

Comment: Works perfectly! Very elegant. Thank you!